# Can I install in UEFI mode with the alternate installer?

Tags: 11.04, alternate, grub-efi, uefi

I'm wondering if it's possible to install Ubuntu 11.04 UEFI mode with the alternate installer. I've read that only `grub-efi` is needed to boot in UEFI mode. How do I install that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out, so for those who are interested, here's how to do it:

After the installation, reboot the computer into a live CD or any Linux CD that can mount the hard drive partitions. Then, do the following: (replace `#` with appropriate partition numbers)

```
### Mounting ###

sudo mount /dev/sda# /mnt            #Mount root (/) partition
sudo mount /dev/sda# /mnt/boot       #Mount boot (/boot) partition 
                                      (if separate from root partition)
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/boot/efi          #Create EFI partition mount point
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi   #Mount EFI partition

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

sudo chroot /mnt                     #Chroot to your installation

### Installing ###

apt-get install grub-efi-amd64  #Install grub EFI bootloader

grub-install --recheck --no-floppy --force
                                     #Install grub bootloader in EFI partition

echo "configfile (hd0,gpt#)/boot/grub.cfg" > /boot/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg
                                     #Tell grub to load grub.cfg from /boot

update-grub                          #Create grub menu list

exit                                 #Exit chroot

### Unmounting ###

sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt/boot/efi
sudo umount /mnt/boot
sudo umount /mnt
```

Comment: `sudo` is redundant with `sudo chroot`. Also, it seems that `grub-install` is invoked in the post installation scrupt of `grub-efi-amd64` as well. I couldn't get this working, the system (desktop with Gigabyte GA-Z68X-UD3H) stops after the boot menu without selecting an OS. Did you perform additional steps? Edit: I don't have a `/sys/firmware/efi` directory

Comment: Okay, it turns out that the mobo with Award BIOS does not have "real" EFI support. What a shame.. http://techreport.com/discussions.x/20941

Comment: Thanks! I've removed sudo from the commands run in the chroot. Sorry for the delay :( There must be some way to have Ask Ubuntu send emails for comments.

Comment: First off thank you for this, I'm having some what of the same problem with 12.10 throwing me to the grub prompt on reboot every time. Pretty sure this is because I'm booting from a UEFI board.

Comment: When you say ¨After the installation, reboot the computer into a live CD or any Linux CD...¨, is that booting in legacy (CSM) mode? Or UEFI mode?