# How do I install on an UEFI Asus 1215b netbook?

Tags: 11.10, live-usb, uefi, grub-efi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 11.10 on a UEFI netbook Asus 1215b using an USB stick.

I created a fat32 efi partition of 100MB, 2GB swap, and 2 ext4 partitions (for root (`/` ) and `/home`, respectively).

While installing, Ubuntu switches to CLI and starts running `efibootmgr`. After a few commands (sadly I don't have a screen grab), it stops displaying text but it's still running judging by the HDD led. Then, there's a weird graphic glitch and the screen turns off (HDD led still indicating activity).

Finally, it just stops, but doesn't turn off. Not even a hard reboot works (holding down the power button a few secs). I have to plug the netbook off and remove the battery.

After that, it still doesn't boot Ubuntu...

Anyway, what can I do? I'm considering following the footsteps [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/index.html) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting).

Edit: here is  the syslog

```
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 00000000ffe1867c
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] IP: [<ffff880066d44c1f>] 0xffff880066d44c1e
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] PGD 14ecc067 PUD 0 
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] CPU 0 
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] Modules linked in: cryptd aes_x86_64 ufs qnx4 hfsplus hfs minix ntfs msdos xfs reiserfs jfs bnep parport_pc rfcomm dm_crypt ppdev bluetooth lp parport joydev eeepc_wmi asus_wmi sparse_keymap uvcvideo videodev v4l2_compat_ioctl32 snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_seq_midi snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec arc4 snd_rawmidi snd_hwdep psmouse snd_pcm snd_seq_midi_event ath9k serio_raw sp5100_tco i2c_piix4 k10temp snd_seq mac80211 snd_timer ath9k_common ath9k_hw snd_seq_device ath snd cfg80211 soundcore snd_page_alloc binfmt_misc squashfs overlayfs nls_iso8859_1 nls_cp437 vfat fat dm_raid45 xor dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log btrfs zlib_deflate libcrc32c usb_storage uas radeon video ahci libahci ttm drm_kms_helper drm wmi i2c_algo_bit atl1c
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] 
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] Pid: 28432, comm: efibootmgr Not tainted 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu ASUSTeK Computer INC. 1215B/1215B
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] RIP: 0010:[<ffff880066d44c1f>]  [<ffff880066d44c1f>] 0xffff880066d44c1e
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] RSP: 0018:ffff88005e2cbab0  EFLAGS: 00010082
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] RAX: 00000000ffe1867c RBX: 0000000000000009 RCX: 00000000ffe1867c
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff88005e2cbbea RDI: ffff88005e2cbb40
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] RBP: 00000000ffe1867c R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000084
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] R10: ffffc9001101ff83 R11: ffffc90011018685 R12: 0000000000000001
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffffc9001101867c R15: ffff88005e2cbbe1
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] FS:  00007f9cdde13720(0000) GS:ffff880066a00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] CR2: 00000000ffe1867c CR3: 000000002dace000 CR4: 00000000000006f0
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] Process efibootmgr (pid: 28432, threadinfo ffff88005e2ca000, task ffff880014f0dc80)
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] Stack:
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009]  ffffc90011010000 ffff88005e2cbac8 0000000000010000 ffff880066d4401d
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009]  000000000000007c ffff880009e84400 0000000000000090 ffff880066d45738
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009]  ffffc9001101867c ffff880066d4331c 0000000000000009 ffffc9001101867b
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] Call Trace:
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009]  [<ffffffff815e9efe>] ? _raw_spin_lock+0xe/0x20
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009]  [<ffffffff811d9c2d>] ? open+0x10d/0x1b0
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009]  [<ffffffff8116554b>] ? __dentry_open+0x2bb/0x320
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009]  [<ffffffff811d9b20>] ? bin_vma_open+0x70/0x70
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009]  [<ffffffff815e9efe>] ? _raw_spin_lock+0xe/0x20
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009]  [<ffffffff811849ee>] ? vfsmount_lock_local_unlock+0x1e/0x30
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009]  [<ffffffff8104303b>] ? efi_call5+0x4b/0x80
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009]  [<ffffffff81042a7f>] ? virt_efi_set_variable+0x2f/0x40
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009]  [<ffffffff814bb125>] ? efivar_create+0x1e5/0x280
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009]  [<ffffffff811d9d63>] ? write+0x93/0x190
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009]  [<ffffffff811d9de4>] ? write+0x114/0x190
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009]  [<ffffffff81167813>] ? vfs_write+0xb3/0x180
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009]  [<ffffffff81167b3a>] ? sys_write+0x4a/0x90
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009]  [<ffffffff815f22c2>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] Code: ec 01 75 f0 41 bc 01 00 00 00 e8 e5 fb ff ff e8 e4 fc ff ff 33 c0 44 0f b7 c0 66 3b c3 73 20 41 0f b7 c0 41 0f b7 d0 03 c5 8b c8 <8a> 00 42 38 04 3a 75 0a 66 45 03 c4 66 44 3b c3 72 e2 33 c0 66 
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] RIP  [<ffff880066d44c1f>] 0xffff880066d44c1e
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009]  RSP <ffff88005e2cbab0>
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] CR2: 00000000ffe1867c
$Oct 21 01:05:17 ubuntu kernel: [ 1220.544009] ---[ end trace 493844b002da4787 ]---
```

Comment: Managed to reproduce the error after following Chen Xiao-Long's answer here http://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer. Maybe now I can have a log available!

Comment: New update: I managed to get the log by mounting /dev/sda2 (my ubuntu root partition) to /mnt and check logs in /mnt/var/logs/installer/syslog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying running the alternate version of 11.10, and then if that doesn't work, try again the x86 or x64 of ubuntu 11.10.

I don't know it worked out, but after like 5 tries of installing Ubuntu 11.10, it finally installed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I don't have time now to try your solution, as I have my term paper to do, but after November I'll give it a shot.

Comment: That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was just wondering could this help?
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting

I am a total IT amateur, but have been using Ubuntu for quite a while, and started some forum research in order to install U on lenovo ideapad s205, to discover that booting UEFI file structure follows some conventions.
I managed to install Ubuntu 11.10 after Win7 when I assigned sda1 as a boot partition (Where Windows7 boot partition resided) and it worked, for ubuntu only though, as I could not load Win7 any more.
Which confirms what is written in the link provided above.
I am planning to find out more detail on this convention when I have time and do a clean install of Ubuntu.
Plse let me know if you discover anything useful in the meantime, and forgive me if this is just a lay person opinion on the problem, it might make sense, who knows

Cheers, 
G

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I have tried it, to no avail :(

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and finally i got Ubuntu installed!

I did it that way:

1. Use Unetbootin to make an usb-stick.
2. Download the distribution you like (Ubuntu daily in my case)! WITH UNETBOOTIN!
3. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> when the asus boot screen appears and choose your usb-stick (not uefi).
4. I installed Ubuntu with standard configuration and partitioning and it it runs very good.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! i'll try it after november. I'm curious: what's the difference between unetbootin and using Ubuntu's own LiveCD Creator?

Answer (score -1):

On my ASUS 1015-B which is basically the same laptop with smaller screen, I have to use CD/DVD to install as USB install fails.

Comment: I don't have a CD drive so I couldn't install Ubuntu that way...