# Very poor NVME performance

Tags: drivers, kernel, filesystem, performance, nvme

I first installed Windows and ran a benchmark on the samsung 950 Pro, and saw 2700 MBps read speed. I did this to confirm that the motherboard could use the full x4 lanes with NVME on the boot device.

In ubuntu, I'm seeing write speeds of 170-200MBps.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I then did a clean install of ubuntu, and ran a test using this [technique](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87035/how-to-check-hard-disk-performance).
Here is the result:

```
$ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/nvme0n1

/dev/nvme0n1:
 Timing cached reads:   23880 MB in  2.00 seconds = 11951.14 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 5194 MB in  3.00 seconds = 1731.18 MB/sec
```

Here is the lspci:

```
$ lspci -vv -s 02:00.0
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller
    Physical Slot: 2-1
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 39
    Region 0: Memory at fb210000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Region 2: I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at fb200000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
```

I did some searching and found a related question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758058/low-pci-e-link-speed-for-950-pro) with no answers. Another post, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698395/poor-io-performance-pcie-nvme-samsung-950-pro), has similar problems but no solution.

Any tips on troubleshooting?

Thanks!

Edit: to clarify, write speeds on windows were also blazing, well above 1500MBps

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm the numbers you provide here are way larger than 170-200MB/s. However they are wrong.

In order to bypass the page cache, causing the reads to go directly from the drive into hdparm's buffers (ie "raw" I/O), you need to use the --direct parameter in hdparm. That is:

```
$ sudo hdparm -Tt --direct /dev/nvme0n1
```

That way your results will be lower but close the actual disk's performance.

Answer (score 2):

Try command line (you may need to `sudo apt install fio` first):

```
fio --name TEST --eta-newline=5s --filename=fio-tempfile.dat --rw=read --size=500m --io_size=10g --blocksize=1024k --ioengine=libaio --fsync=10000 --iodepth=32 --direct=1 --numjobs=4 --runtime=60 --group_reporting
```

For additional details, see:
https://askubuntu.com/a/991311/50254