# Boot hangs after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04.1

Tags: boot

I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04.1 and all seemed to go OK.  But when I rebooted, the system hangs.

Early in the boot process, I get the error message:
Error no video mode activated

The last lines shown are:

```
[   5.901767] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[   5.906814] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[   5.916187] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[   5.921562] piix4_smbus 0000:00:14.0: SMBus Host Controller at 0xb00, revision 0
[   5.929183] piix4_smbus 0000:00:14.0: Auxiliary SMBus Host Controller at 0xb20
[   5.937026] impi message handler version 3.92
[   5.942086] PTP clock support registered
[   5.942222] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
```

I can ping the system when it's hung, but I can't ssh into it.

I can boot into recovery mode, bring up a root shell, and see all my files.

When I resume normal boot from recovery mode, I get a flickering error message:

```
[   256.522705] do_IRQ: 1.36 No irq handler for vector
```

This continues indefinitely.

The specs on my video card are:

```
EVGA GeForce GTX 660Ti PCI-E 3.0 2048MB 2 DVI, 1 HDMI 1.4, 1 DisplayPort; 
2048MB GDDR5 Memory (192 bit); 
Base Clock: 915 MHz; 
Memory Bandwidth: 144.192 GB/sec Supports NVIDIA CUDA: 1344 CUDA Cores
```

Is this problem related to the 18.04.1 video driver?
How do I fix it?

Comment: Did you uninstall video driver before upgrading, and then boot with nomodeset (like a new install) and install new nVidia driver? See section on adding nomodeset to linux line in grub menu when booting. http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it  I have a slightly newer nVidia card and open source drive works well.  You may also need to first purge old driver? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2383560&p=13735336#post13735336

Comment: I did not knowingly uninstall the video driver.

I booted with nomodeset in the Linux boot command.  This time the boot process got further.  One step failed with the error
   Failed to start VirtualBox Linux Kernel module

Comment: The last line completed in the boot was  

Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes

Comment: So is this an install in VirtualBox? I do not know VirtualBox and its unique issues. Often last posted line is not issue, but one several lines above it.  Have you tried recovery mode, that includes nomodeset automatically and boots to a menu of repair options or command line.

Comment: No, it's not an install in VirtualBox.  It's an upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04.1.  I'm just reporting the symptoms I see, since I don't know enough to make sense of them.  I'm hoping that someone knows what the next steps in the boot process are so they can identify where it's going wrong.

I've tried tried recovery mode.  I can get to a root shell, but can't proceed much past that.

Comment: If you can get to / (root) command line it has booted and then is a gui issues. Were you running Unity or some other desktop? And then run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`  ? Or what errors do you get?

Comment: I created an 18.04.1 boot stick and was able to boot into Ubuntu off the stick, including the graphical desktop.  I'll try the apt update & upgrade.

Comment: If you cannot get to / with direct boot, then from live installer you may need to chroot into your install and run repairs. https://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380 You may need other repairs than those in link, but those would be a start.

Comment: I booted into the installation stick, selected Try Ubuntu, and installed the boot-repair ap.  Boot-repair complained of an unusual RAID.  When prompted with "[dmraid]Packages may interfere with MDraid.  Do you want to remove them?" I clicked "No".  I stopped short of changing anything on the system and generated this boot info report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/93s5PB5rTr/

Comment: Are you using RAID? Boot-Repair often has to ask if RAID or LVM as both use /dev/mapper. It looks like a standard LVM type install. But not familiar with those installs and issues with them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88234/discussion-between-tom-speer-and-oldfred).

Comment: Afraid I do not know RAID at all, so cannot add much to discussion.

Comment: Here are videos showing the symptoms: https://youtu.be/hPJy6iNGvpM, https://youtu.be/ivZwgy45QPQ

Comment: You booted to command line, but then seem to have video issues. Have you at command line updated? `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade`? Then have you installed nVidia driver? example shows -396 which may not be correct for your card. https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers Updated driver search by nVidia model, do not download, just check correct driver version
http://www.geforce.com/drivers   Any version of driver from time released to most current that nVidia says is correct for your card should work. The ppa has the newest drivers, some too new.

Comment: Doing the update followed by upgrade when I was in the 16.04 graphical UI is how I got into this situation in the first place.  It didn't occur to me to do it again in from the command line recovery mode.  Is that really a good idea?

I'll search for the right driver and try installing it.  

The live boot media works OK, so isn't that an indication that the generic drivers in the distribution are appropriate for my card?

Comment: Here's another video in which I include the parameters "ast.modeset=0 nouveau.modeset=0" to the Linux boot command and attempt to continue the boot: https://youtu.be/7np0lPBULTA

Comment: If booting to tty, I did not think you needed or had gui. My GT620 works the same with nVidia driver and nouveau driver as near as I can tell.