# Boot-repair on legacy mode for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, boot-repair, grub-legacy

I just installed a new Ubuntu 20.04, and would like to repair the Grub of another Ubuntu 20.04 that's on a separate partition, and which is the installation I love. Let's call the Ubuntu with broken Grub: MyUbuntu.

- I know MyUbuntu to be fine if only I could boot it. **Context**: MyUbuntu was working well, then I ran the famous "[boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)" by YannUbuntu, and then I never managed to boot into it again. I ended up installing a new Ubuntu from live disk.
- I am on legacy mode. Thus I cannot select MyUbuntu from the new Ubuntu's Grub (I don't get the Grub loader GUI, it just boots directly into the new one).
- I am on Acer Aspire E5-576-76J8.
- I do not care for the new Ubuntu. I do not need to be able to dual boot.

In this situation, how to make MyUbuntu boot again?
There should be a way. The disk is not broken, the installation in itself is untouched, I just simply ran a boot-repair. How to restore from this situation.

[image: Disk and partition visualization]
[image: The boot folders of the working and of the non-booting installation]

Comment: You tag legacy, but it looks like you have a FAT32 partition which would be for UEFI boot. Screenshots do not help much, but posting the link from Boot-Repair's Summary report would help a lot. Boot-Repair suggests if asking for help to post link, Are you always booting in UEFI mode or always BIOS/Legacy mode. Mixed boot will confuse things. Acers typically require UEFI update and setting "trust" on UEFI boot entry. Similar: Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: Oldfred, sorry for taking so long to answer. I've immediately been punished because most of my pastebins expired 3 days ago.
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VTKGY3bFYQ/ 

The above one is based on an output I had sent myself via mail. I don't have a preference for legacy vs UEFI boot, and would just like to understand the appropriate one. Thanks a lot for informing me about FAT32 pointing to UEFI, that's helpful. My whole problem seems to come from the fact that I installed my own Ubuntu by using a legacy stick, could that be?

I'd only like to be able to boot back into the old "MyUbuntu" agai

Comment: Following up on the post you linked to, I've not been able to solve my problem, as I get the "you need to load kernel first" error message in grub. This after having added both "<ubuntu>" and "<legacy>" to my "select an UEFI file as trusted for executing"

Comment: So, as a conclusion, I now again lost the possibility to lo into any of the 2 ubuntus (exactly what I was fearing). When in the grub menu though, and pressing escape, I at least get access to the grub terminal. This didn't help me last time. To add insult to injury, I can now not boot from a USB anymore (it's not in my list of bootable devices) so that I have to revert to "legacy" again which is probably got me in trouble in the first place.

Comment: I've tried the commands displayed here within the grub terminal, and after insmod normal and normalm, I still get "you need to load kernel first" https://www.google.com/amp/www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/ways-to-rescue-or-recover-grub-menu

Comment: With two installs do not run Boot-Repair's auto fix. Only use advanced mode and select install and drive using advanced mode tabs. you have to be consistent. Only boot in UEFI mode & repair in UEFI mode or only boot in BIOS mode & repair in BIOS mode. Then set system to boot in that mode by default. Also choose to install newest kernel which may force reset of some other issues. Since UEFI hardware probably better to use UEFI, but either should work. Not sure why you have so many kernels. it should now only keep two.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will not run boot-repair again, that's for sure. I don't know what to do nevertheless. By adding options listed in the boot-menu under BOOT/ (I added bootx64.efi and grubx64.efi) I was able to boot into "Debugging Ubuntu" again (though it did show me a blue "System reset" page, that I just left using the "Esc" button).
My problem is really simple to explain: in EFI mode, the PC doesn't detect any USB stick. What am I supposed to do? In the end, all I want is to install a bootloader in "MyUbuntu" or anyhow make "MyUbuntu" be bootable.

Comment: Setting "Secure Boot" to "disabled" while using UEFI as boot mode, I can actually see my USB stick.
But that doesn't help me in understanding what I have to do to make "MyUbuntu" bootable. I don't care about the "dual" installation.
I just want to be able to boot into MyUbuntu on which I was doing some NGO work. I cannot use my work PC for that, which is why I ask the questions on weekends. Sorry for that.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/JMdpUaV.jpg - Options under BOOT/

Comment: I would still use Boot-Repair unless you want to use chroot. But use Boot-Repair's advanced mode, choose your install which one is MyUbuntu? Full reinstall of grub, and choose drive. Check newest kernel also so it does full updates. https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ UEFI chroot, must include ESP - efi system partition
http://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380
To chroot, you need the same 32bit or 64 bit kernel. Best to use same version.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot

Comment: The option to "repair" MyUbuntu (GRUB location > OS to boot by default) is not allowed when not running grub-repair from a live-disk. However, I do not manage to boot from a USB live disk in UEFI mode.

Please find below the pics from the boot-repair running within the debugging ubuntu. 
1. I can only select sda3 as OS to boot by default (does not let me select sda2 where MyUbuntu is, though it does detect it).
2) I can select a separate boot partition: is that what you mean by "choose drive"?
3) In GRUB options, what to select?

Comment: boot location: https://pasteboard.co/JMPhvqA.png

Comment: grub options: https://pasteboard.co/JMPhTZP.png

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Sorry for being helpless, but I just haven't found the solution by myself.

Comment: I missed first time this: "sda2 is 97 % full", that probably prevents any updates as you have no working room. Still not sure why so many old kernels which can be removed. If not converted from MBR to gpt, then install would be UEFI. I think "trust" is only required for UEFI boot. With BIOS/legacy boot, you are just booting a drive & UEFI/BIOS does then not know what is booting. Use live installer to make repairs. Most times it should work from a Linux install, but some seem to find it works better from live installer.

Comment: Hello dear oldfred. As stated, I cannot select another default when not running from a live disk.
https://pasteboard.co/JVDwaGN.png

Comment: Concerning the 97% full, I have since cleaned up and am at around 82% full with around 15Gb of free space. As a reminder, as last we talked was a while ago: I had a working ubuntu installing on Acer, and ran the boot repair program and since cannot boot into myUbutu. I installed another ubuntu next to it for better analysis. I also have trouble booting into USB.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308820/boot-repair-on-legacy-mode-for-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: If you cannot boot old install from new install's grub is the old install otherwise damaged and needs repairs? It should boot or give some sort of error message. And if Boot-Repair does not offer to change grub to boot that install, it would indicate some issue.

Comment: I've sent an email chain to the support email of boot repair oldfred. Thanks for your fast replies. Should I join you in the email chain? :)

Comment: Not sure what you sent. Yann at Boot-Repair is interested in issues with his program, not your specific issues which should be addressed here or in Ubuntu forums.

Comment: You are right. It's not easy to understand who can help. I don't want to steal all of your time either. I've looked through some forums and it seems like acer is always a bit complicated with this. Currently, I simply can't even use the USB stick anymore. I felt very close when I suddenly managed to boot into it twice in a row, and then could run 2 boot repair options (which didn't solve my problem, though at some point I landed in grub at startup which is the farthest I've got).

Comment: I'm wondering whether there is a type of timer in the bios that decides when the "next" bootloading option should be chosen. Maybe the USB simply isn't fast enough? But that also makes no sense, as it currently doesn't get detected in neither f12 boot options menu nor in f2 bios menu.

Comment: UEFI will only boot one Ubuntu install. And that now is your new install of Ubuntu. But then grub should let you boot any other system you have installed. I have so many, mostly now expired Ubuntu installs, I have to turn os-prober off. Then I just add the few I may still want in 40_custom. So if os-prober is not finding your old install it says you have issues. Have you run fsck on it? Make sure partition is unmounted and run e2fsck: http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122643/discussion-between-lionel-trebuchon-and-oldfred).

Comment: I cannot boot into USB which makes your answer difficult to follow... Also when pressing F12 to see the bootloader options, I only get different grub terminals with barely any functionality.

Comment: sudo parted -l

Model: ATA HFS256G39TND-N21 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  787MB   786MB   fat32                 boot, esp
 6      787MB   798MB   10.5MB                        bios_grub
 2      1060MB  81.1GB  80.0GB  ext4
 3      81.1GB  161GB   80.0GB  ext4            win   msftdata
 4      161GB   248GB   87.0GB  ntfs            data  msftdata
 5      248GB   256GB   8000MB  linux-swap(v1)        swap

Comment: Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but
Linux says it is 512 bytes.
Ignore/Cancel?

Comment: ```sudo parted -l
Partition Table: gpt 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  787MB   786MB   fat32                 boot, esp
 6      787MB   798MB   10.5MB                        bios_grub
 2      1060MB  81.1GB  80.0GB  ext4
 3      81.1GB  161GB   80.0GB  ext4            win   msftdata
 4      161GB   248GB   87.0GB  ntfs            data  msftdata
 5      248GB   256GB   8000MB  linux-swap(v1)        swap

Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but
Linux says it is 512 bytes.
```

Comment: oldfre, I managed to solve my problem, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case:

0. Create a USB stick with the same Ubuntu version as the one you want to repair.
1. In Acer bios menu, make sure you have secure boot enabled, but remove the `Password on boot option` (so as to be able to reboot often, see point 2.).
2. Reboot many (>10) times until seemingly at random, my key was recognized as bootable medium (if you are in the F12 menu, select the key manually, if you are in the F2 boot menu, at least put the key in first spot of the list, and wish yourself good luck for the coming reboots).
3. Make sure there is space (>X Gb, >10%) left on the partition you want to boot into (>9 Gb,`\dev\sda2` for me). Make sure you have a fat32 partition flagged as `boot` and `esp` on the same same disk (you can verify that with Gparted from the stick).
4. [Install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) boot-repair on the live session.
5. Run advanced boot-repair with checked: `GRUB options > SecureBoot` and `GRUB options > Purge GRUB and reinstall it` and `GRUB location > check separate /boot/efi partition: sda1`. This will analyse the disk, and end up giving you commands to paste in the command line (do that):

```
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda2" dpkg --configure -a
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda2" apt-get install -fy
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda2" apt-get purge -y grub*-common shim-signed
```

Then, click `Forward`: In my case, this resulted in an error: *GRUB is still present. Please try again.*

6. Run advanced boot-repair with: default options, but uncheck `separate /boot/efit partition` and check `Place GRUB into sda`. For me, this resulted in the error *GRUB is still present.*
7. Despite the error, try rebooting now without the stick.