# Boot into safe mode from Grub command line

Tags: grubrescue

I accidentally installed the wrong graphics drivers (installed nvidia drivers and I don't actually have an Nvidia card!) and now Ubuntu boots into Grub command line. How do I boot ubuntu into safe mode so I can uninstall the Nvidia drivers?
Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes `exit` or just  press enter may continue boot. Or you may need to chroot into your system from live installer to make repairs. If you just installed incorrect driver, you still should get grub menu and then boot second line or recovery mode entry. If only grub>, you also made some other changes. UEFI chroot, must include ESP - efi system partition
http://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380

Comment: As I stated in the question I can only boot into grub>.

Comment: Then chroot & repair system.

Comment: this one worked https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely