# Can not boot Ubuntu 22.04, dual boot installation, no GRUB loader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

good people,

I am trying to dual boot Windows 10 and latest LTS Ubuntu (22.04 Jammy Jellyfish), first time installation was sucesuful on second drive, but when restarted it did not show bootloader menu and just booted to Windows.

I am asuming that it has something with boot/efi because I did not alocated space for it, just for root and swap.

Now it wont boot USB flash drive at all, tried another drive, tried another .iso, another Linux distribution, tried Fedora.

Can only boot when change from UEFI to Legacy, but after initial screen it just show CLI and frozes. PC definitely support UEFI because I installed Ubuntu already before.

Is GRUB missing, how to repair it?

Comment: did you change the boot order in the UEFI? You probably want to set the device you wish to boot from as the highest-priority boot device.

Comment: Yes, USB-HDD is set on top, it worked before. When I change to Legacy mode it shows diferent name, USB-Generic Flash Drive, on UEFI shows USB-HDD

Comment: can you boot to either the drive or the Ubuntu install if you choose them directly from the UEFI boot menu (accessible using some fn key specific to your BIOS usually)?

Comment: Is your second drive a physical drive, or just a partition on your first drive (Microsoft calls both "drives" and really confuses the issues)?  Is the second drive removable (if it is, read launchpad bug 1396379 if you want to make the drive bootable).  The EFI partition is just a FAT filesystem, look for the .../EFI/ubuntu files shimx64.efi and grubx64.efi, if present, grub got installed.

Comment: Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer typically uses the ESP - efi system partition on first drive, whichever UEFI/BIOS makes as first drive. Often just the Window's ESP. Is this an HP. Some systems only let you change boot order in UEFI settings, not UEFI boot menu. And if UEFI system with UEFI installs, never change to legacy as that just confuses things & may break it.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that OS probe is disabled in GRUB 2.06 that is shipped with 22.04, so you have found the "gotcha". However, it can be resolved by editing the grub config file to enable successful probing for other OS's.

1. Use your installation media to boot into a live session.
2. Mount the installed, but unobtainable partition if not already done
   automatically.
3. Edit /etc/default/grub eg `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` in a terminal.
4. Add the live `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false`
5. Save and exit
6. In a terminal, run `sudo update-grub`
7. Reboot the system.

Grub should then appear with your Windows and Ubuntu installation choices.

Credit should be given to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404268/1152076) in a related question, and the source for that on [OMG! Ubuntu!](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/12/grub-doesnt-detect-windows-linux-distros-fix). Finally, credit is due to Christopher Barnett from the Explaining Computers Youtube channel who first alerted me to this issue.

Comment: Easy to tell if this is a problem, just run sudo update-grub, and the output will say if os-prober is executed or not.  Missing the GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER line in /etc/default/grub is another indication it's not disabled.

Comment: This solution does not work on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a related problem as I just upgraded 20.04 to 22.04 and was getting boot errors.  I found the following article on the Ubuntu community forum which solved my problem:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

This basically rebuilds grub.

Answer (score 0):

[This worked](https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/) for me:

Open a windows terminal and run it as administrator, then enter

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into the same problem, i.e. I installed Ubuntu 22.04LTS alongside Windows 10 on my laptop hp Elitebook 8460p, and after successful installation, on restarting the system it wasn't able to find any boot device.
I tried several suggested solutions but none of them worked for me, then I tried booting with Windows 10 bootable USB flash drive and instead of installing windows, I chose "Repair Windows" option and them chose "Repair Startup" option and all is set.
That's how I ended up fixing this issue. Hope someone can find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

I set up Ubuntu 22.04 over 20.04 with a dual boot system with Windows 10. When I restarted system, grub rescue prompt appeared. After trying some suggestions without any success, I tried the following: I set up 22.04 again with download and application of latest updates. Then, I started the system using the try Ubuntu option from the usb with the setup. I setup boot-repair, run it and followed the instructions from boot-repair. The problem has been solved.

Answer (score -1):

Install Ubuntu 20.04, then upgrade to 22.04. Extra pain, but worked for me.