# Can't choose Win7 and Ubuntu in GRUB

Tags: grub2, system-installation, usb-installation

I installed Ubuntu alongside with the Win7, rebooted PC, removed flash with installation files as the guide said and recieved a GNU GRUB screen with several options: Try or Install Ubuntu, Ubuntu(safe graphics), OEM install(for manufacturers), Test memory.

Why there is no option to choose Win7 and non-safe graphics Ubuntu and how shoul I deal with those issues?

Comment: If you are using 22.04, have you enabled os-prober by setting `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` as detailed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404268/167115)?

Comment: Otherwise, windows may be in a hibernated state and you are supposed to have windows in a fully shut down state when installing Ubuntu. For one thing, you should [disable the quick boot feature in BIOS if one exists](https://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/using-quick-boot-feature-of-bios.html).

Comment: If windows is in a hibernated state, you should be able to see the partition when you run `lsblk` or `blkid` and it should show up as an NTFS partition. **If** ***and only if*** **the NTFS partition does show up** and fixing the os-prober problem does not solve the issue, then, ***as a last resort***, you can use ntfsfix to fix the hibernated windows partition as described in [this particular answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/532753/167115). **It should be noted that this is possibly unsafe and could corrupt some Windows data so this should be a last resort.**

Comment: If the NTFS partition does not show when you run `lsblk` or `blkid` then please edit your question and post the output of those commands.

Comment: You haven't provided any Ubuntu product/release details; but the Try/Install choice you describe implies to me it wasn't installed at all as that try/install question exists only on uninstalled media. You also said rebooted PC then removed media; thus implying you potentially rebooted the installation media as it hadn't been removed in time.  If you boot again does it occur?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GRUB does not detect Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows)

Comment: If you're seeing "Try..." or "Install..." options then you din't remove the installation media. It's that simple.