# Installing Ubuntu on M.2 drive and Windows on an SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, ssd

What is the correct way to install Ubuntu and windows on a new computer, on the first M.2 disk I want to install ubuntu and as a second system Windows 10 on an SSD.

Installing Win on the M.2 is not an option since 99% of the time I use Ubuntu so I don't want to install Windows on the M.2

Should I install Windows on the SSD first and then Ubuntu on the M.2?
Or should I install Ubuntu on the M.2 first and then Windows on the SSD?
Does it allow me to install Windows 10 on a second drive?

Comment: Install Windows on the SSD. Remove the SSD and install Ubuntu on the M.2. Replace the SSD and boot Ubuntu. In Ubuntu terminal run `sudo update-grub`.  If you are installing Ubuntu 22.04 or later, you may need to activate os-prober before updating. see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1404268/43926

Comment: Windows likes to install its ESP - efi system partition to default boot drive. We have seen where it installs to different drive than user expected. Some UEFI have drive settings like "disabled" so you can turn off the M.2 drive without having to remove it. Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only installs to whatever drive UEFI says is first drive. That may be fastest drive or port order. But M.2 may be first? It probably depends on your UEFI.

Comment: Thanks..., my bios does not allow to disable the M.2, I will try the option suggested by Cameron