# Bootloop after installing dualboot kubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu, lenovo

when installing kubuntu, the system tell an error (but i didnt notice it because it says restart my laptop). after restarting my laptop it bootlooping. blinking twice in lenovo logo (my laptop is lenovo thinkpad t480s) then it shows reset system in the left corner and its keep bootlooping.

hint : cant boot in linux or windows, but its still can make it to bios. i have been trying to set boot priority to windows and disable ubuntu. but it stay in the top.

sorry for my poor english

Comment: Similar issue, but user did not say exactly what fixed his issue. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404259/getting-grub-menu-to-work-on-dual-boot-ubuntu-22-04-windows-11-currently-boots