# I can't boot into Ubuntu after installing it

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, grub-efi

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad t470s I followed the instructions to install Ubuntu but I can't boot into after multiple try I couldn't do anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make grub menu appear instead grub minimal bash-like in booting?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting)

Comment: Many Lenovos have this setting. Lenovo T450 Problem with boot repair GRUB - Boot Lock issue
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2494747
Lenovo Locked UEFI/BIOS setting:
https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.redd.it%2Foygxuo193ui41.jpg Lenovo Thinkpad T495 Boot Order Lock
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404259/getting-grub-menu-to-work-on-dual-boot-ubuntu-22-04-windows-11-currently-boots

Comment: How far into the boot process does it get? Is there an error message? I'd recommend checking through the BIOS settings, and validate the boot and EUFI options are set correctly for your system to start Ubuntu.