Can't Install Ubuntu 22.04 (Dual Boot)
I can't install Ubuntu on my Windows 11 machine for dual booting. Every time I get the error:

executing grub-install dev/nvme0n1p2 failed.

So far I've tried:

Unallocating the disk before the installation and manually partitioning while installing Ubuntu.
Going straight for the Ubuntu installation and choosing "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows boot manager" option and using the slider to automatically allocate space.

Neither of these worked. I still get the error:

executing grub-install dev/nvme0n1p2 failed.

So I tried to fix grub loader. By following a couple of guides, I tried ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair tool. (I don't know if it is allowed to post links here but if they are needed I can provide links to the said tutorials.) Unfortunately that didn't work so I tried to install grub loader manually by following another guide. I got an error saying that I didn't have enough space in the EFI partition. (and yes I am sure I was trying to install grub while I was mounted on the EFI partition, nvme0n1p2 in my case.)
If it would be of any help, I realized that the Disk app in Ubuntu shows that the EFI partition shows that 100% of the partition is in use. However, in Windows; diskmgmt.msc shows that the EFI partition is 100% free.
Additional information:

I have secure boot disabled.
I am trying the dual boot install on a Lenovo LOQ 15APH8 model laptop. It has an RTX 4060 GPU and Ryzen 7 7840HS CPU with 16 GBs of RAM.
I am creating the bootable USB with Rufus and I've tried both MBR and GPT partitioning.
I haven't tried resizing my EFI partition, and since I already have deleted my EFI partition while messing with partitions, I don't want to do it again. (I can do it if it is necessary though)
The problem was present even before deleting the EFI partition, and I have wiped the disk and reinstalled everything after breaking the system. So Windows created a new EFI partition.
Bitlocker and fast startup was turned off.

The summary report from boot-repair
paste.ubuntu link for boot-repair report
Tried dosfsck
Report summary for the most recent boot-repair try.
Any help is appreciated.

Post link to the Summary report from Boot-Repair. But if shown 100%, is bitlocker on or Windows fast start up which sets hibernation flag? Those settings in Windows prevent the Linux NTFS driver from seeing Windows partitions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

@oldfred Bitlocker and fast startup is off. I am adding the summary report to the original post.

@oldfred I should also mention that before reinstalling Windows 11, the efi partition was partition 1, after the reinstall it is partition 2 (I have 100 mb of unallocated space for some reason and I can't reclaim it). That's why in the summary report I have provided the efi partition is nvme0n1p1. I still get the same error after the reinstall of Windows 11 when I'm trying to install Ubuntu though. If that would make a difference I can try to install Ubuntu once more and post the report summary from boot-repair.

Not sure why it shows a Windows boot manager in MBR, line 97. With UEFI the gpt protective MBR is not used for booting. You can try from live installer, so unmounted,  a dosfsck of your ESP. sudo fsck.vfat -t -a /dev/nvme0n1p1 see also man dosfsck

@oldfred I tried dosfsck and added the result to the original post. What should I do now?

You now have this: Warning: NVram is locked (Ubuntu not found in efibootmgr). Sorry should have said p2 on dosfsck. But you ran it ok. The p1 is Microsoft system reserved (MSR) &  is unformatted. Usually first or second partition is ESP & MSR is after ESP. Some Lenovo systems have setting in UEFI to lock (for Security) changes to UEFI. Check UEFI settings: The Device Guard BIOS setting locks down the boot order to internal HDD/SSD only.
Lenovo Thinkpad T495 Boot Order Lock
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404259/getting-grub-menu-to-work-on-dual-boot-ubuntu-22-04-windows-11-currently-boots

@oldfred I don't know if that would be the solution, but I found the solution :) Will post the solution as an answer now.

Turns out, my problem was with the original EFI partition (/dev/nvme0n1p2 in my case.)
Upon reading the boot-repair summaries, I realized that boot-repair couldn't use the space on the EFI partition since it was full or it seemed to be full to Linux. I am not good with partitions so I might be wrong.
The solution was to resize the EFI partition. To do this I followed a YouTube tutorial and created another EFI partition that is bigger, old one was 100MB and the new is 300MB. Then, I restarted the system and I deleted the old EFI partition using a 3rd party software but it could probably be done with diskmgmt.msc. After that I booted into the live Ubuntu stick and performed another boot-repair (You can find guides on how to do that easily.). Then everything was working again.
Note: I saw what @oldfred suggested after I fixed the problem. Their solution would probably also work, since the problem seems to be with Lenovo.

Did you copy Windows UEFI boot files into new ESP. And create a new UEFI entry for Windows. UEFI boot entries use GUID/partUUID of ESP. So new ESP will have new partuuid for UEFI boot entries.
