Dual boot Ubuntu with windows 11
I'm trying to boot into Ubuntu but the problem is that the boot manager menu is not showing me the USB boot option.
It says that the system doesn't have any USB boot optiion.
How to fix this issue.
N.B: I used Rufus to create a bootable flash drive and installed the LTS version of Ubuntu/
My pc brand is Lenovo --> IdeaPad 3 15iau7 so you can say it's a modern laptop/I disabled the secure boot option and still the same problem.

Some machines need the USB present at shutdown to make it available for the next boot.  Some machines might lump the USB under the hard disk boot options. Not sure what the "boot manager" is, does the UEFI boot menu (some key at power-up to let you choose boot devices/oses) show the USB?

According to this https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/3-series/ideapad-3-15iil05/81we/solutions/ht500207-how-to-boot-from-usb-disk-in-the-bios-boot-menu-windows-8-windows-10-ideapadlenovo-laptops you have to use FN+F12.

Some Lenovo have additional UEFI settings for security to prevent USB boot. The Device Guard BIOS setting locks down the boot order to internal HDD/SSD only.
Lenovo Thinkpad T495 Boot Order Lock
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404259/getting-grub-menu-to-work-on-dual-boot-ubuntu-22-04-windows-11-currently-boots

I figured out the solution to this problem(finally) : First, you need to check wether the USB drive is corrupted,if so you need to buy a new one.Second, disable secure boot under the security section as well as Fast boot under the boot section .Finally, turn off the bitlocker encryption  .If you are using the Home version of windows 11,you then need to disable it using powershell.Don't forget to run it as administrator.And you should be free to go.
If you still encounter the same issue, trying out different ports would likely solve it.

Done.Took me a little while to solve it on my own.It was frustrating.Hope no one  would ever run into this problem again.
