Can't boot into Ubuntu after installation using live USB
My main issue was that even after installing Ubuntu twice through a live USB, every time I select the hard disk I have installed it to upon restarting, it just refuses to boot and goes back to the boot select menu.
I have tried Boot-Repair's suggestion of creating a separate boot partition at the start of the disk since it said that the boot file in the original install was too far away for the BIOS to detect, however even after following these instructions I still cannot boot into Ubuntu.
My device used to run Windows 10 and I had selected the option to erase
Windows and replace it with Ubuntu.
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2czZWfFfQR/ Here's the URL I was told to copy down after boot-repair finished the job.
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

Default settings: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub2 of
sda2 into the MBR of sda.
Grub-efi would not be selected by default because no ESP detected.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________


The boot files of [sda2 (end>100GB)] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)

User settings: _________________________________________________________________

The settings chosen by the user will reinstall the grub2 of
sda2 into the MBR of sda,
using the following options:  kernel-purge sda3/boot
Grub-efi will not be selected by default because no ESP detected.
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s


/boot added in sda2/fstab
Rename /dev/sda3/boot to boot_bak
Mount /dev/sda3 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/boot
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 apt-get -y update
Running in chroot, ignoring command 'start'

================== dpkg -l | grep linux- before kernel purge ===================

ii  cpp-13-x86-64-linux-gnu                       13.2.0-23ubuntu4                         amd64        GNU C preprocessor for x86_64-linux-gnu
ii  cpp-x86-64-linux-gnu                          4:13.2.0-7ubuntu1                        amd64        GNU C preprocessor (cpp) for the amd64 architecture
ii  linux-base                                    4.5ubuntu9                               all          Linux image base package
ii  linux-firmware                                20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.4          amd64        Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-generic-hwe-24.04                       6.8.0-45.45                              amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-6.8.0-45                        6.8.0-45.45                              all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 6.8.0
ii  linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic                6.8.0-45.45                              amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 6.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04               6.8.0-45.45                              amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic                  6.8.0-45.45                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-24.04                 6.8.0-45.45                              amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                          6.8.0-45.45                              amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  linux-modules-6.8.0-45-generic                6.8.0-45.45                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-45-generic          6.8.0-45.45                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-sound-base                              1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu7                     all          base package for ALSA and OSS sound systems
ii  linux-tools-6.8.0-45                          6.8.0-45.45                              amd64        Linux kernel version specific tools for version 6.8.0-45
ii  linux-tools-6.8.0-45-generic                  6.8.0-45.45                              amd64        Linux kernel version specific tools for version 6.8.0-45
ii  linux-tools-common                            6.8.0-45.45                              all          Linux kernel version specific tools for version 6.8.0

========================== Purge kernel of /dev/sda2 ===========================

linux-generic available

The following additional packages will be installed:
linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
DEBCHECK debOK, linux-generic
DEBCHECKLINUX debOK
ls /mnt/boot-sav/sda2/boot/: lost+found
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y linux-headers-*

PackSET@_progressbar1.pulse()
age 'linux-headers-6.8.0-35-lowlatency' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
amd64-microcode bpfcc-tools bpftrace ieee-data intel-microcode iucode-tool
libbpfcc libc-dev-bin libc-devtools libc6-dev libclang-cpp18 libclang1-18
libcrypt-dev libllvm18 linux-image-generic-hwe-24.04 linux-libc-dev
manpages-dev python3-bpfcc python3-netaddr rpcsvc-proto thermald
ubuntu-kernel-accessories
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
linux-generic-hwe-24.04* linux-headers-6.8.0-45*
linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic* linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
Removing linux-generic-hwe-24.04 (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Removing linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04 (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Removing linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Removing linux-headers-6.8.0-45 (6.8.0-45.45) ...
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y linux-image-*

age-unsigned-6.8.0-41-generic' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
amd64-microcode bpfcc-tools bpftrace ieee-data intel-microcode iucode-tool
libbpfcc libc-dev-bin libc-devtools libc6-dev libclang-cpp18 libclang1-18
libcrypt-dev libllvm18 linux-libc-dev manpages-dev python3-bpfcc
python3-netaddr rpcsvc-proto thermald ubuntu-kernel-accessories
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic* linux-image-generic-hwe-24.04*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
Removing linux-image-generic-hwe-24.04 (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Removing linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
W: Last kernel image has been removed, so removing the default symlinks
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic
Purging configuration files for linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
W: Last kernel image has been removed, so removing the default symlinks
rmdir: failed to remove '/lib/modules/6.8.0-45-generic': Directory not empty

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 apt-get install -y linux-generic

The following additional packages will be installed:
linux-headers-6.8.0-45 linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic linux-headers-generic
linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic linux-image-generic
Suggested packages:
fdutils linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
linux-generic linux-headers-6.8.0-45 linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic
linux-headers-generic linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic linux-image-generic
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../0-linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic_6.8.0-45.45_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../1-linux-image-generic_6.8.0-45.45_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-6.8.0-45.
Preparing to unpack .../2-linux-headers-6.8.0-45_6.8.0-45.45_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-6.8.0-45 (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../3-linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic_6.8.0-45.45_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../4-linux-headers-generic_6.8.0-45.45_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../5-linux-generic_6.8.0-45.45_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Setting up linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
I: /boot/vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img.old is now a symlink to initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic
I: /boot/vmlinuz is now a symlink to vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic
Setting up linux-headers-6.8.0-45 (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Setting up linux-headers-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Setting up linux-image-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Setting up linux-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic (6.8.0-45.45) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic
W: Kernel configuration /boot/config-6.8.0-45-generic is missing, cannot check for zstd compression support (CONFIG_RD_ZSTD)

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 apt-get install -y linux-base

linux-base is already the newest version (4.5ubuntu9).
linux-base set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.

=================== dpkg -l | grep linux- after kernel reinstall
ii  cpp-13-x86-64-linux-gnu                       13.2.0-23ubuntu4                         amd64        GNU C preprocessor for x86_64-linux-gnu
ii  cpp-x86-64-linux-gnu                          4:13.2.0-7ubuntu1                        amd64        GNU C preprocessor (cpp) for the amd64 architecture
ii  linux-base                                    4.5ubuntu9                               all          Linux image base package
ii  linux-firmware                                20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.4          amd64        Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-generic                                 6.8.0-45.45                              amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-6.8.0-45                        6.8.0-45.45                              all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 6.8.0
ii  linux-headers-6.8.0-45-generic                6.8.0-45.45                              amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 6.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                         6.8.0-45.45                              amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic                  6.8.0-45.45                              amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                           6.8.0-45.45                              amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64                          6.8.0-45.45                              amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  linux-modules-6.8.0-45-generic                6.8.0-45.45                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-45-generic          6.8.0-45.45                              amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-sound-base                              1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu7                     all          base package for ALSA and OSS sound systems
ii  linux-tools-6.8.0-45                          6.8.0-45.45                              amd64        Linux kernel version specific tools for version 6.8.0-45
ii  linux-tools-6.8.0-45-generic                  6.8.0-45.45                              amd64        Linux kernel version specific tools for version 6.8.0-45
ii  linux-tools-common                            6.8.0-45.45                              all          Linux kernel version specific tools for version 6.8.0



======================= Reinstall the grub2 of /dev/sda2 =======================

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.12-1ubuntu7

==> Reinstall the GRUB of /dev/sda2 into the MBR of /dev/sda

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 2048 
    of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks for (,gpt3)/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_gpt biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    biosdisk fshelp fat exfat ext2 ntfs ntfscomp part_msdos
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg /grub/i386-pc/core.img

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  MSWIN4.1: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/grubx64.efi /efi/boot/mmx64.efi


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on sda2

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M / R7 M370] from Intel Corporation Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, noble, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: R00ET69W (1.44 )(1.44) from LENOVO
The firmware seems EFI-compatible, but this live-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   hasBIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
sda3    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda2    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda3    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 6145EA7E-2541-4FF4-802D-380B43750F13
       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
sda1     2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
sda2  1034240 1953523711 1952489472  931G Linux filesystem
sda3     4096    1034239    1030144  503M Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sdb: 28.67 GiB, 30784094208 bytes, 60125184 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x00030bb9
     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *     2048 60125151 60123104 28.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA WDC WD10SPCX-08S:;
1:1049kB:2097kB:1049kB:::bios_grub;
3:2097kB:530MB:527MB:ext4:/boot:;
2:530MB:1000GB:1000GB:ext4::;
sdb:30.8GB:scsi:512:512:msdos: USB  SanDisk 3.2Gen1:;
1:1049kB:30.8GB:30.8GB:fat32::boot, lba;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                   
├─sda1                                               aa297f19-7255-4586-adde-028e2bd3f0ae             
├─sda2 ext4     6f287bcf-12bb-4e4d-be9f-6a6a2a912893 8734e8d7-75ca-4e1b-ae6c-9e5d67aaca5e             
└─sda3 ext4     489e9dbb-a893-4580-85e0-64bdc86f54f5 8b2e7f60-b389-4169-a25e-20b8610e8a03             /boot
sdb                                                                                                   
└─sdb1 vfat     5E8C-EE60                            00030bb9-01                          UBUNTU 24_0 

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2              858.6G   1% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda3              338.1M  18% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
/dev/sdb1               22.9G  20% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda2              ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda3              ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdb1              vfat            ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

====================== sda2/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   6f287bcf-12bb-4e4d-be9f-6a6a2a912893
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda2/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/6f287bcf-12bb-4e4d-be9f-6a6a2a912893 / ext4 defaults 0 1
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
UUID=489e9dbb-a893-4580-85e0-64bdc86f54f5  /boot       ext4    defaults      0       2

======================= sda2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

==================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 796.632347107 = 855.377469440  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 796.632328033 = 855.377448960  boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
   1.889896393 = 2.029260800    boot/vmlinuz                                   1
   1.889896393 = 2.029260800    boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic                  1
   1.889896393 = 2.029260800    boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
   9.452774048 = 10.149838848   boot/initrd.img                                1
   9.452774048 = 10.149838848   boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic               1
   9.452774048 = 10.149838848   boot/initrd.img.old                            1

===================== sda2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18133 Apr  4 10:12 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43202 Apr  4 10:12 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14513 Apr  4 10:12 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Apr  4 10:12 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13120 Apr  4 10:12 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Apr  4 10:12 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 Apr  5 11:36 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr  4 10:12 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr  4 10:12 41_custom

======================== sda3/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) =========================

Ubuntu   6f287bcf-12bb-4e4d-be9f-6a6a2a912893
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

==================== sda3: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
   0.131809235 = 0.141529088    grub/grub.cfg                                  1
   0.131793976 = 0.141512704    grub/i386-pc/core.img                          1
   0.148685455 = 0.159649792    vmlinuz                                        1
   0.148685455 = 0.159649792    vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic                       1
   0.148685455 = 0.159649792    vmlinuz.old                                    1
   0.211563110 = 0.227164160    initrd.img                                     1
   0.211563110 = 0.227164160    initrd.img-6.8.0-45-generic                    1
   0.211563110 = 0.227164160    initrd.img.old                                 1

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1


What brand/model system? Some like HP require you to change settings in UEFI/BIOS settings. Others like Acer require you to set "trust" on ubuntu boot entry. Do you have latest available firmware for your system? My Skylake motherboard, has not had an update for several years, but has latest available. Your system is UEFI, but you have installed in old BIOS boot mode. The far from start of drive was more for older BIOS only systems. And often better solution was / at beginning of drive & then /home or data for rest of drive.

This was done on a a Thinkpad e560. I tried changing it to UEFI only, but that still didn't fix the issue.

Does your Lenovo have boot order lock or similar? Lenovo Thinkpad T495 Boot Order Lock
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404259/getting-grub-menu-to-work-on-dual-boot-ubuntu-22-04-windows-11-currently-boots Lenovo ThinkPad E595  re-installed & then it worked?
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2454063
