Cannot install Ubuntu 24.04.1 unless secure boot is disabled
I have a problem installing ubuntu 24.04.1 on the lenovo laptop thinkpad t14s gen5, no matter how I create bootable usb in rufus all the time I have this error:
Secure Boot Violation,
Invalid signature detected
Check Secure Boot Policy in Setup.
So i have disabled secure boot installed ubuntu alongside with windows 11, then rebooted enabled secure boot and again I have the same error.

24.04.01 is not a valid version number. Download the installer again.

Check UEFI settings. Some have Lenovo Locked UEFI/BIOS setting: And some have The Device Guard BIOS setting locks down the boot order to internal HDD/SSD only. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404259/getting-grub-menu-to-work-on-dual-boot-ubuntu-22-04-windows-11-currently-boots Do you have latest UEFI firmware & SSD firmware? Lenovo T14 is update to ThinkPad T400, T410, T420, T490. series, so any issues with similar models may apply.

Did you reformat the ISO? or write it to media as it was intended?  ie. have you tried using the dd-mode which does not change the ISO during write? as other options that reformat ISO can cause failure to boot on some hardware.  If you install Ubuntu without secure boot enabled, it won't setup the system for secure boot installing; you install with secure boot enabled which allows you to then boot with secure boot enabled or disabled.

Sorry my type version I have downloaded is 24.04.1vform official Ubuntu page. Laptop in the new model fully updated to the latest drivers and latches from Microsoft. When I created the media I chooses ISO version and UEFI.

This fixed the issue for me on my Thinkpad Gen5 with Windows preinstalled:
https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/Enable_Secure_Boot_for_Linux_Secured-core_PCs.pdf
tldr: You have to enable "Allow Microsoft 3rd Party UEFI CA" in the BIOS -> Security -> Secure Boot

Thanks, this is working.
