# How to restore Grub after a unbuntu upgrade

Tags: grub2, upgrade, boot-repair

I upgraded from ubuntu LTS 16 desktop to ubuntu LTS 18 destop. Now the grub does not work and it goes to `Grub Rescue` mode directly.

I tried Boot Repair (https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/) After I apply "Recommended repair", I got the following message:

`grub-pc purge cancelled.`

The pastebin for the boot info is at:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kHWfrNmGvk/

Please help me.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Why is purge cancelled? You also show you installed Grub customizer as you have all the grub proxy files. It looks like you have both grub's scripts and the Customizer proxy scripts in your /etc/grub.d folder. See line 277 in report. Was there some reason you installed Customizer?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure why it is cancelled. The log is at: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/csT2ZGQyRD/ . I ran boot repair twice, both failed with the same error. I did not intentionally use grub customizer. Another point, my previous grub may be old. During the upgrade, I was prompt to choose existing grub config or overwrite it, I think I chose to keep. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Did you run the fix suggested in line 490 as you have broken dependencies'. And I would totally uninstall grub customizer. You may have to manually remove all the proxy files in /etc/grub.d to avoid issues of duplication.

Comment: Yes I tried "sudo apt --fix-broken install" but still got the same error. I am wondering if the broken install is in my hdd. Same question for /etc/grub.d: is it in the hdd? right now I am running ubuntu live from usb, so all operations are not done in hdd. I don't know how to access hdd right now. BTW, the /etc/init.d has the following content: ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/grub.d$ ls
00_header        10_linux      20_memtest86+  30_uefi-firmware  41_custom
05_debian_theme  20_linux_xen  30_os-prober   40_custom         README

Comment: Boot-Repair does a minimal type of chroot into your install, so you can run commands besides the reinstall of grub. You can just do a full chroot to update & reconfigure a broken system. UEFI chroot, must include ESP - efi system partition
http://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380
 chroot with UEFI, LVM, encryption on NVMe drive
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2349833&p=13602088#post13602088
To chroot, you need the same 32bit or 64 bit kernel. Best to use same version.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot

Comment: I have fixed the problem by following your excellent guide on chroot and then remove two offending packages. Then boot-repair works like charm! Many thanks!