# Grub-installl command doesn't work inside chroot

Tags: command-line, grub2, system-installation, live-cd, grub-efi

While restoring grub after installing windows, after mounting everything(bin, proc, run, dev, dev, dev/pts), and after chroot /mnt/ command, I don't have Grub-installl command,
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: /usr/sbin/grub-install

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 live-USB to reinstall grub after installing windows. When I'm in chroot mnt, I don't have Grub-installl command to reinstall grub. @guiverc

Comment: How can I bring Grub-installl command inside chroot mnt mode?

Comment: I had  a Ubuntu release 20.04, after installing windows I lost my grub.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include _all_ the commands you ran to set up the `chroot` environment. We need to know what you have done. For instance, mounting `/run` seems odd. And how exactly did you mount them? We need to know the details to be able to help.

Comment: See these details on chrooting & grub install. https://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380 & If LVM and NVMe drive: chroot with UEFI, LVM, encryption on NVMe drive
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2349833&p=13602088#post13602088

Comment: Try: nano /etc/resolv.conf In the open file paste these lines:
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
Ctrl+O Save File Ctrl+X Close nano
Continue running:
dpkg --configure -a
apt -f install
apt -m install
apt update
apt install grub
grub-install /dev/????
apt dist-upgrade
apt autoremove
apt clean