Can't enter grub menu to enter recovery(to fix Ubuntu no keyboard and mouse at login)maybe because of update?
Using Ubuntu 22.04
HP Bios
So here is my problem,
One day I start building programs from source (wxWidgets based KiCAD etc...) and after downloading a bunch of packages and I suspect mostly because of that occasional sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade I did.
Now I assume This answer should do the trick once I'm able to log into bash but when I boot into the system now it gets stuck and the Ubuntu GUI login menu with the keyboard and mouse stuck
I've tried entering the black and white grub menu to enter the "Advanced recovery mode thing" but all I'm able to is to reach HP's Startup Menu grey on white with blue menu by hitting esc at boot repeatedly and even in the "Boot Menu" there I'm able to only boot into "UEFI-ubuntu" two other for "UEFI IPV4 and IPV6 Network" and "Boot from file"
And after entering the "UEFI-ubuntu" option trying to hold / oscillate the switch yiels the same Ubuntu login screen I can't move my mouse and keyboard at.
After choosing the UEFI-ubuntu option and hitting / holding shift doesn't do anything putting me into the normal login screen with the unresponsive keyboard and mouse but they sure are seen by the PC as I can still navigate the Bios menu with them.
Any idea how to approach it?
I still have the boot USB drive of the installed Ubuntu if that helps but I assume it's not like with windows where you can somehow use it to recover the current system?

What model HP? Did you update UEFI firmware? If not you should, but that often resets UEFI to defaults. Many have additional settings beyond UEFI Secure boot for secuity and/or settings for USB ports. Make sure full USB port or a mouse/keyboard setting is correct.

HP-Z1-G8-Tower-Desktop-PC when I come to update teh bios from the "Start up" menu it won't let me and error me out but maybe that's not the way to do it... Anyhow if's that's unnececcery I'd like to try to solve it and fix my ubuntu while making as little changes as possible...

My assumption so far is that I need to enter ubuntu's recovery mode externally somehow and maybe an apt update would solve it.

HP only has a few systems in fwupdate, first thing I do is uninstall fwupdate as my motherboard is not supported either.  You have to download from HP directly to FAT32 partition or use Windows/DOS. Did you check UEFI settings for USB port or keyboard settings? You may be able to chroot into system, to update from a live installer. UEFI chroot, must include ESP
http://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380
chroot with UEFI, LVM, encryption on NVMe drive
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2349833&p=13602088#post13602088
