Lubuntu 24.04 installation. bootloader failed
I am trying to install Lubuntu 24.04 to old motherboard MSI J1900l (It's Intel SoC Celeron J1900). Previously, the CentOS system was installed on the computer. I checked installation with both values: UEFI and LEGACY+UEFI for parameter Boot mode select in BIOS
And parameter Security boost is disabled.
I have downloaded iso (torrent from lubuntu.me) and made bootable USB stick with Rufus application. I can use this bootable USB stick as a Live USB. However, I cannot install Lubuntu on hard drive (SATA SSD) with it.
The Lubuntu distro is installing with Calamares 3.3.5
Partitions:
Creating new GPT partition table on /dev/sda (Samsung SSD 750 EVO 120GB)...
Create new 300MIB partition on /dev/sda (Samsung SSD 750 EVO 120GB)
Set flags on 300MiB fat32 partition to boot
Create new 114168MIB partition on /dev/sda (Samsung SSD 750 EVO 120GB) with entries lubuntu_2404
Set up new fat32 partition with mount point /boot/efi
Install Lubuntu on new ext4 system partition

After reboot there is a grub command-line.
grub> ls
(proc) (memdisk) (hd0) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) 
grub> ls (hd0)
Device hdo: No known filesystem detected - Sector size 512B - Total size 117220824KiB
grub> ls (hd0,gpt2) 
        Partition hd0,gpt2: Filesystem type ext* - Label `lubuntu_2404' - .......
grub> ls (hd0,gpt1)
    Partition hd0,gpt1: Filesystem type fat, UUID .......

The following are parameters for bootloader@bootloader job in Calamares:
Key              Value
==============================================
efiBootLoader    grub
efiBootloaderid  ubuntu
fallback         /initramfs-linux-fallback.img
grubCfg          /boot/grub/grub.cfg
grubinstall      grub-install
grubMkconfig     grub-mkconfig
img              /initramfs-linux.img
kernel           /vmlinuz-linux
timeout          10

The installation failed with error:
The bootloader could not be installed. The installation command <pre>grub-install 
--target=x86_64-efi --efi- directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=ubuntu --force</ pre> returned 
error code 1.

So, I tried to run this command in terminal:
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=ubuntu --force
grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.

That's true. There are neither file modinfo.sh nor directory /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi
The following is the content of the parent directory:
lubuntu@lubuntu:/usr/lib$ ls -1pr /usr/lib/grub
i386-pc/
grub-sort-version
grub-multi-install
grub-mkconfig_lib

There is also directory grub-legacy:
lubuntu@lubuntu:/usr/lib$ ls -1pr /usr/lib/grub-legacy/
update-grub

What am I doing wrong, and how to install lubuntu on my computer?
Additonal info
1.Partition info from fdisk:
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.39.3).
Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 111.79 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 750 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D46C3C91-0455-4642-8631-D154BF70EE30

Device      Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1    4096    618495    614400   300M EFI System
/dev/sda2  618496 234436544 233818049 111.5G Linux filesystem

2.lscpu output
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ lscpu

Architecture:             x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):         32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:          36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:             Little Endian
CPU(s):                   4
  On-line CPU(s) list:    0-3
Vendor ID:                GenuineIntel
  Model name:             Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  J1900  @ 1.99GHz
    CPU family:           6
    Model:                55
    Thread(s) per core:   1
    Core(s) per socket:   4
    Socket(s):            1
    Stepping:             3
    CPU(s) scaling MHz:   63%
    CPU max MHz:          2415.7000
    CPU min MHz:          1332.8000
    BogoMIPS:             4000.00
    Flags:                fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnttsc_deadline_timer rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb pti tpr_shadow flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat vnmi

3.Symlinks
3.1 I tried to add symbolic link /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi pointing to the /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc like this question from lubuntu.me. However, it didn't work
3.2 I found modinfo.sh from a folder x86_64-efi with the following command:
find / -name modinfo.sh

Then I add a symbolic link /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi pointing to the found x84_64-efi directory. After I run the same command grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=ubuntu --force  I have got an error failed to get canonical path of /boot/efi

Did you verify the ISO before making the bootable media?  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

You show FAT32 partition with boot flag, but not with esp flag? Does it have both? you want UEFI install of grub or grub-efi-amd64. If installing old BIOS boot mode on gpt, you have to have a bios_grub partition, not the ESP. Ten years ago when first converting from BIOS on old system to UEFI on new system, I would use gpt, but have both ESP & bios_grub. But now almost all systems are UEFI.

Your issue maybe how you wrote the ISO using rufus, as the rufus app allows you to reformat the ISO (via options) and thus cause the installer to mis-read your BIOS/uEFI settings (getting them from the thumb-drive/install-media which should have none!) causing an incorrect boot setup to be written for your hardware.  I suggest you use a simple CLONE of the ISO to your media as documented by Ubuntu/Lubuntu docs (ie. no changed options) unless you use options specifically for your intended machine

@David - I verified the ISO. However, I don't think it was necessary since the torrent mechanism tracks the accuracy of the downloaded image.

@oldfred - Actually,  I chose the partitioning suggested by the installer. I'm not well-versed in this matter. In the BIOS, there's a "Boot mode selection" option with two choices: [UEFI] and [LEGACY+UEFI]. I've tried both of them. Do you think I should change the partitioning and flags?

We have had some have issues with the Legacy+UEFI. Often better to use UEFI. That that only controls the default boot mode of installed system. You have to choose UEFI or Legacy/BIOS/CSM every time when booting USB flash drive. And ESP - efi system partition should be only partition with boot,esp flags.

@guiverc - I tried also balenaEtcher to make bootable USB stick. It doesn't have any options at all. With rufus I tried to change partition scheme: 1. GPT - UEFI (non SCM) 2. MBR - BIOS or UEFI

@oldfred - Yes. ESP flag for /dev/sda1/ was set. And [UEFI] option have been selected in BIOS. There is  another problem. When I symlinked  folder /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi. Command with grub-install raises error failed to get canonical path of /boot/efi´. It's strange, because /boot/efi should mount to /dev/sda1. I will expand the question

Many newer users find Boot-Repair easier to use to repair/reinstall grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Sometimes advanced mode is required. Or UEFI chroot, must include ESP - efi system partition
http://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380 But we are seeing issues with modprobe efivars # gives error not found as using kernel folder. If so, Boot-Repair & chroot needs this also:
mount -t efivarfs efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

I cannot install Lubuntu 24.04 on my computer directly. So, I tried to install previous releases of Lubuntu. The first release successfully installed was Lubuntu 20.04.05. Then I upgraded it to version 24.04 step by step. Each step was like the following:
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo reboot 0
...
sudo do-release-upgrade

It takes time, but now I have last Lubuntu
