Can not boot back into Ubuntu, after installing windows (dual boot)
I followed this link: Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot
Specifically this step: Converting Ubuntu into UEFI mode. This was because I believed that ubuntu was in BIOS mode, and I knew that windows install was in UEFI mode because I had reinstalled the BIOS for my motherboard before installing Windows.
Following the step ran without issue, I was asked to copy the commands into terminal and agree to uninstalling GRUB. However it did not fix the problem. After the first attempt of boot-repair using the Converting Ubuntu into UEFI mode step, I got the logs before my second attempt of using boot-repair: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hQM3shyktn/
> boot-repair-4ppa2081                                              [20240903_1601]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1 and looks at sector 
    2048 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks for (,gpt2)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_gpt biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p6: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the boot sector of 
                       sdb and looks at sector 0 of the same hard drive for 
                       core.img, but core.img can not be found at this 
                       location.
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdb: /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on nvme0n1p2
OS#2 (windows):   Windows 8 or 10 on nvme0n1p5

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] from Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, noble, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 3.J0(5.17) from American Megatrends International, LLC.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot enabled according to mokutil - Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com.
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(3,GPT,1022f70c-b97c-460a-8093-9f0e4db5928b,0x45d97800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000033000100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot0001* UEFI:  USB DISK 2.0 PMAP, Partition 2 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/USB(8,0)/HD(2,GPT,eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba17-9014c007d874,0xb8b5a0,0x27a0)0000424f

2086830028e23b8ec983082f67c6fdc8   nvme0n1p3/Boot/bootx64.efi
13bbe79f47b4d57f791e51f5c01f7ac8   nvme0n1p3/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi
2086830028e23b8ec983082f67c6fdc8   nvme0n1p3/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
aa6ccfec39f89d76e4d6013a88d32b2b   nvme0n1p3/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   hasBIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    34 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p3   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p5   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p6   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
nvme0n1p3   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme0n1p6   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p6   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
sda2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 7F1D6A2B-F86F-43FA-9DCE-641B9C67B551
              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1       2048       4095       2048     1M BIOS boot
nvme0n1p2       4096 1171879935 1171875840 558.8G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p3 1171879936 1172084735     204800   100M EFI System
nvme0n1p4 1172084736 1172117503      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p5 1172117504 1951948799  779831296 371.9G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p6 1951948800 1953521663    1572864   768M Windows recovery environment
Disk sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk identifier: 7F9666EA-D7C1-455A-9ACF-9C26B6B83AD7
     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
sda1     34      32767      32734   16M Microsoft reserved
sda2  32768 3907026943 3906994176  1.8T Microsoft basic data
Disk sdb: 28.91 GiB, 31042043904 bytes, 60628992 sectors
Disk identifier: EED3DE8A-ACD3-4541-BA15-9014C007D874
        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sdb1        64 12105119 12105056  5.8G Microsoft basic data
sdb2  12105120 12115263    10144    5M EFI System
sdb3  12115264 12115863      600  300K Microsoft basic data
sdb4  12115968 60626943 48510976 23.1G Linux filesystem

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:2000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA WDC WD20EZAZ-00G:;
1:17.4kB:16.8MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
2:16.8MB:2000GB:2000GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
sdb:31.0GB:scsi:512:512:gpt: USB DISK 2.0:;
1:32.8kB:6198MB:6198MB::ISO9660:hidden, msftdata;
2:6198MB:6203MB:5194kB::Appended2:boot, esp;
3:6203MB:6203MB:307kB::Gap1:hidden, msftdata;
4:6203MB:31.0GB:24.8GB:ext4::;
nvme0n1:1000GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:CT1000P1SSD8:;
1:1049kB:2097kB:1049kB:::bios_grub;
2:2097kB:600GB:600GB:ext4::;
3:600GB:600GB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp, no_automount;
4:600GB:600GB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres, no_automount;
5:600GB:999GB:399GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
6:999GB:1000GB:805MB:ntfs::hidden, diag, no_automount;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                     
├─sda1                                                    4d8b7528-60d2-4c36-9374-83b09e99be47                          Microsoft reserved partition
└─sda2      ntfs     94A406A7A4068C44                     1c248494-0c00-4714-a40a-56575754759e Harddrive                Basic data partition
sdb         iso9660  2024-08-27-16-23-26-00                                                    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS amd64 
├─sdb1      iso9660  2024-08-27-16-23-26-00               eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba14-9014c007d874 Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS amd64 ISO9660
├─sdb2      vfat     3C53-CAEB                            eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba17-9014c007d874 ESP                      Appended2
├─sdb3                                                    eed3de8a-acd3-4541-ba16-9014c007d874                          Gap1
└─sdb4      ext4     5817f507-011a-48ef-8ed5-9d9cda8f9bcb 625e7033-be0b-4c1c-ab34-eb648126c781 writable                 
nvme0n1                                                                                                                 
├─nvme0n1p1                                               5e1dd8a9-4774-49d9-8d2a-6af939f0b3a4                          
├─nvme0n1p2 ext4     2f3b3fc2-303e-4462-bba0-b0537627d5bd 891dd806-248d-4d35-9d76-42c0c9a715f0                          
├─nvme0n1p3 vfat     C877-8EDC                            1022f70c-b97c-460a-8093-9f0e4db5928b                          EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p4                                               a35b685c-ab25-4fff-9937-cfa15956610d                          Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p5 ntfs     84607BEF607BE5F8                     346230af-9dbb-45ff-8a45-fe2427663c71                          Basic data partition
└─nvme0n1p6 ntfs     5AFEFA7AFEFA4DAF                     dbcdcbfa-6231-40dc-b97d-3d52d2d247eb                          

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                               Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p2                                                123.2G  72% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2
/dev/nvme0n1p3                                                   68M  29% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p5                                                135.7G  64% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
/dev/nvme0n1p6                                                 89.5M  88% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6
/dev/sda2                                                       1.4T  24% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sdb1                                                          0 100% /cdrom
efivarfs                                                       72.9K  39% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p2                                                ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/nvme0n1p3                                                vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p5                                                fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p6                                                fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda2                                                     fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdb1                                                     iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048,iocharset=utf8

======================== nvme0n1p2/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/2f3b3fc2-303e-4462-bba0-b0537627d5bd / ext4 defaults 0 1
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
UUID=C877-8EDC  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

================= nvme0n1p2: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 266.281227112 = 285.917290496  boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
 543.750247955 = 583.847383040  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 543.906494141 = 584.015151104  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic                  2
 543.750247955 = 583.847383040  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic                  1
 543.906494141 = 584.015151104  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 255.580074310 = 274.427015168  boot/initrd.img                               18
 204.082912445 = 219.132358656  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic               3
 255.580074310 = 274.427015168  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic              18
 204.082912445 = 219.132358656  boot/initrd.img.old                            3

=================== nvme0n1p2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 722 Apr  5 11:36 35_fwupd

mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 


Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to fix packages) and reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of
nvme0n1p2,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p3/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 24.04 LTS entry (nvme0n1p3/efi/****/shim****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !

The boot files of [nvme0n1p3 (end>100GB)] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a ESP partition (FAT32, 100MB~250MB, start of the disk, boot flag). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option of [Boot Repair].If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\shim****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)

All attempts at using the boot-repair in default mode or repeating the Convert Ubuntu into UEFI mode resulted in an error during boot repair.

    File "/usr/bin/glade2script-python3", line 2319, in set_widget
    exec( arg )
    File "<string>", line 1
    self._label9.set_text('''sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2" dpkg --configure -a\nsudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2" apt-get install -fy\nsudo chroot "mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2" apt-get install -y grub-efi-amd64-signed shim-signed linux-headers-generic
    SyntaxError: unterminated triple-quited string literal (detected at line 1)

I think I messed up the boot-repair and I might not be able to salvage the ubuntu part of the dual boot.
Edit:

I have retried reflashing my usb but error persists.
And assuming that Ubuntu partition is unsalvageable, if I just delete the parition and follow the install Ubuntu after Windows 11 method, would the dual boot still work?


Not sure where triple ' came from? Bug in Boot-Repair. Boot-Repair tries to walk you though a minimal chroot to reinstall the UEFI version of grub. But you should always be able to do a full chroot. UEFI chroot, must include ESP - efi system partition
http://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380 Some now also need to mount efivars. UEFI settings or include in chroot mount -t efivarfs none /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482909 &
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2490084

I did at one point cancel the boot-repair by hitting control - C, prior to bug occuring.

This looks like you just need to add Ubuntu to the UEFI. If you still have your 24.04 install media disk/usb or a previous one for 22.04, or possibly even your boot repair disk and the follow the instructions at https://askubuntu.com/questions/831216/how-can-i-reinstall-grub-to-the-efi-partition

@oldfred How do I know which partition to use for your solution?https://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380

I have tried https://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380 with gpt2 (Notice the gpt# in the list of commands). i have also changed sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi   #Mount EFI partition to the partition that contains the Ubuntu OS.

I have tried flashing my usb with the boot-repair. But when the pc starts up, there is a black screen with "ATION" in white text. Then the computer shuts down. It will not boot with that live usb. But it works with Ubuntu on usb.

If you look at your Boot-Repair summary report you will see your ESP - efi system partition is p3, so /dev/nvme0n1p3 or in grub partition 3. Drive may be 0 or1 as sometimes flash drives are promoted to first drive (0). Your p1 is a bios_grub partition which for UEFI boot you do not need. What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Does escape key after UEFI/BIOS screen bring up grub menu? Make sure settings are for UEFI boot and that you made an UEFI bootable live installer. Some tools make on for both and you then must select UEFI each time you boot live installer.

My motherboard is b450 tomahawk max. Video card is rx580 8gb. CPU is R5 3600.
So the solution to the boot-repair error was as @oldfred mentioned, make sure your usb is in efi mode / gpt mode. I used rufus tool and diskpart on windows11 (optional) to flash the usb in efi mode.
I then ran the log function of boot-repair. This is the log:
boot-repair-4ppa2081                                              [20240910_0320]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1 and looks at sector 
    2048 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks for (,gpt2)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_gpt biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p6: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/bootx64_original.efi /efi/boot/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/mmx64.efi


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on nvme0n1p2
OS#2 (windows):   Windows 10 or 11 on nvme0n1p5

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] from Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, noble, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 3.J0(5.17) from American Megatrends International, LLC.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot enabled according to mokutil - Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com.
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(3,GPT,1022f70c-b97c-460a-8093-9f0e4db5928b,0x45d97800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000033000100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot0001* UEFI:  USB DISK 2.0 PMAP, Partition 1 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/USB(6,0)/HD(1,GPT,5f8e4b3f-e0ae-401c-8797-71e0ef9c31f3,0x800,0x39d17a0)0000424f

66f69798ad23240e43b7ba0044a914c4   nvme0n1p2/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
66f69798ad23240e43b7ba0044a914c4   nvme0n1p2/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi
cfc91f581a0eb379f573d7bbced9061c   nvme0n1p3/Boot/bootx64.efi
0dddc55d593fc13c3ab3cb750e1a188a   nvme0n1p3/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi
cfc91f581a0eb379f573d7bbced9061c   nvme0n1p3/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
378f8a2aae778974836aea7a73116b74   nvme0n1p3/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   hasBIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    34 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   no-grubenv, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p3   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p5   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p6   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
nvme0n1p3   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
nvme0n1p6   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p6   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
sda2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk identifier: 7F9666EA-D7C1-455A-9ACF-9C26B6B83AD7
     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
sda1     34      32767      32734   16M Microsoft reserved
sda2  32768 3907026943 3906994176  1.8T Microsoft basic data
Disk nvme0n1: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 7F1D6A2B-F86F-43FA-9DCE-641B9C67B551
              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1       2048       4095       2048     1M BIOS boot
nvme0n1p2       4096 1171879935 1171875840 558.8G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p3 1171879936 1172084735     204800   100M EFI System
nvme0n1p4 1172084736 1172117503      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p5 1172117504 1951948799  779831296 371.9G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p6 1951948800 1953521663    1572864   768M Windows recovery environment
Disk sdb: 28.91 GiB, 31042043904 bytes, 60628992 sectors
Disk identifier: D9FE9D7D-1066-4ACD-87FE-F0355DA6B85F
     Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
sdb1   2048 60628895 60626848 28.9G Microsoft basic data

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:2000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA WDC WD20EZAZ-00G:;
1:17.4kB:16.8MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
2:16.8MB:2000GB:2000GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
sdb:31.0GB:scsi:512:512:gpt: USB DISK 2.0:;
1:1049kB:31.0GB:31.0GB:fat32:Main Data Partition:msftdata;
nvme0n1:1000GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:CT1000P1SSD8:;
1:1049kB:2097kB:1049kB:::bios_grub;
2:2097kB:600GB:600GB:ext4::;
3:600GB:600GB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp, no_automount;
4:600GB:600GB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres, no_automount;
5:600GB:999GB:399GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
6:999GB:1000GB:805MB:ntfs::hidden, diag, no_automount;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL       PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                        
├─sda1                                                    4d8b7528-60d2-4c36-9374-83b09e99be47             Microsoft reserved partition
└─sda2      ntfs     94A406A7A4068C44                     1c248494-0c00-4714-a40a-56575754759e Harddrive   Basic data partition
sdb                                                                                                        
└─sdb1      vfat     08AF-1607                            5f8e4b3f-e0ae-401c-8797-71e0ef9c31f3 UBUNTU 24_0 Main Data Partition
nvme0n1                                                                                                    
├─nvme0n1p1                                               5e1dd8a9-4774-49d9-8d2a-6af939f0b3a4             
├─nvme0n1p2 ext4     2f3b3fc2-303e-4462-bba0-b0537627d5bd 891dd806-248d-4d35-9d76-42c0c9a715f0             
├─nvme0n1p3 vfat     C877-8EDC                            1022f70c-b97c-460a-8093-9f0e4db5928b             EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p4                                               a35b685c-ab25-4fff-9937-cfa15956610d             Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p5 ntfs     84607BEF607BE5F8                     346230af-9dbb-45ff-8a45-fe2427663c71             Basic data partition
└─nvme0n1p6 ntfs     5AFEFA7AFEFA4DAF                     dbcdcbfa-6231-40dc-b97d-3d52d2d247eb             

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p2         123.1G  72% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2
/dev/nvme0n1p3            68M  29% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p5         135.1G  64% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
/dev/nvme0n1p6          86.8M  89% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6
/dev/sda2                1.4T  24% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sdb1               23.1G  20% /cdrom
efivarfs                72.9K  39% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p2         ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/nvme0n1p3         vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p5         fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p6         fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sda2              fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdb1              vfat            ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

====================== nvme0n1p2/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p2/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/2f3b3fc2-303e-4462-bba0-b0537627d5bd / ext4 defaults 0 1
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
UUID=C877-8EDC  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

==================== nvme0n1p2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

================= nvme0n1p2: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 282.207042694 = 303.017504768  grub/grub.cfg                                  1
 543.750247955 = 583.847383040  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 543.906494141 = 584.015151104  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic                  2
 543.750247955 = 583.847383040  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic                  1
 543.906494141 = 584.015151104  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 255.580074310 = 274.427015168  boot/initrd.img                               18
 204.082912445 = 219.132358656  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic               3
 255.580074310 = 274.427015168  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic              18
 204.082912445 = 219.132358656  boot/initrd.img.old                            3

=================== nvme0n1p2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18133 Apr  4 10:12 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43202 Apr  4 10:12 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14513 Apr  4 10:12 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Apr  4 10:12 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13120 Apr  4 10:12 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Apr  4 10:12 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr  4 10:12 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr  4 10:12 41_custom

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/sda2 /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 


Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of
nvme0n1p2,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p3/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 24.04 LTS entry (nvme0n1p3/efi/****/shim****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !

The boot files of [nvme0n1p3 (end>100GB)] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a ESP partition (FAT32, 100MB~250MB, start of the disk, boot flag). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option of [Boot Repair].If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\shim****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)

I then ran the boot repair but had this error:
"Locked-NVram detected".
I will disable secureboot in bios and see if it fixes the issue. After disabling secure boot and rebooting. The screen said
a configuration change was requested to disable issuing a block sid authentication

I hit F10 to accept the request. New error:
Locked-NVram detected. Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 24.04 LTS entry (nvme0n1p3/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !

Referring to @oldfred links on issue.
trying this: Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi - Not Found (Dual Boot Ubuntu with Windows 10)

This probably isn't relevant to your situation, but I'm posting in case it helps anyone. I had a different reason for running Boot-Repair, but I ran into the same exact error:
File "/usr/bin/glade2script-python3", line 2319, in set_widget
    exec( arg )
    File "<string>", line 1
    self._label9.set_text('''sudo chroot................

I was running Boot-Repair from my regular Ubuntu installation because I had somehow messed up my boot setup by running Boot-Repair from Ubuntu installed on an SSD connected via USB. Running Boot-Repair from the USB drive had left me unable to boot my regular installation without the USB drive plugged in, and even unable to run an Ubuntu live USB.
Running Boot-Repair from my regular install, it prompted me to purge grub and shim signed via the terminal, which I did:

After doing as I was told, Boot-Repair served me up a most vexing instruction:

Entering "_label9" into a terminal does nothing, of course. So there I was having removed grub and shim signed, which freaked me out because I figured my system would be unbootable. After reattempting Boot-Repair several times and trying all sorts of things to no avail, what finally worked was reinstalling shim signed and grub via the following:
sudo apt-get install shim-signed
sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64

Then when I tried Boot-Repair again, I had the option the uncheck the box to purge grub when reinstalling, which had been off limits on my previous attempts, despite grub already having been purged. This time Boot-Repair ran to completion with no issues.
A bit more background on how I got here: after manually cloning my partitions to a new drive via some combination of GParted and Ubuntu Disks, I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04, but after upgrading to 22.04, I kept running into problems with shim-signed whenever I would try to upgrade some things, and when I tried to upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04. I tried everything I could find in the forums, like adding the correct flags to the boot partition using GParted, and finally resorted to Boot-Repair. Moral of the story, be extremely careful with Boot-Repair! Side note: don't check the repair filesystems option if you have any Veracrypt partitions on the drive.
